# Onclick function in anchor tag is not working

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

This is my code

```
    <div id="bodyForm" style="display: none" class="feedback-modal feedback-css" data-html2canvas-ignore="true">
    <div class="feedback-header" id="headerDiv">
        <a class="feedback-close" id="closeSnip" onclick="close();">X</a>
        <h4 id="feedbackHeader">Contact Development (Beta)</h4>
    </div>
```

close() is not working

```
function close(){
    $j("#bodyForm").css("dsiplay", "none");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = "small";
         document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style = "";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].draggable = true;
        return false;
}
```

i tried event listener its not working too please help

Comment: you misspelled *dsiplay*

Comment: and you have set display: none inline, so initially it won't show anything

Comment: Looks to me like your `div#bodyForm` is missing the `</div>` close tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the js:

```
document.getElementById("closeSnip").onclick = close;
```

and remove the onClick attribute from the html

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As shown in the picture. Maybe you typed a wrong word.